# Can I integrate Reporting Services and Virtual Earth?

Tags: reporting-services, virtual-earth

Our system receives status information from fleets of buses.  We currently use Reporting Services 2008 to present a list of daily events, such as vehicle breakdowns, speeding, passenger counts, etc.  I'd like to add an interactive map to visually indicate the geographic location of each event.  Unfortunately, I can't see an easy way to embed a Virtual Earth map inside a report.  I was toying with the idea of creating a custom renderer to directly output a GeoRSS feed.  Alternatively, I could add a hyperlink which would open a separate browser window with the map; however I'm not sure how to transfer the active result data.

I would like to know if anyone has tried to do this before, and if perhaps there is a simpler option that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to Reporting Services 2008 R2, you can use spatial data to indicate the locations on a map.